'Invoke-Sqlcmd : Must declare the scalar variable "@Environment"
Error:

'Invoke-Sqlcmd : Must declare the scalar variable "@Environment".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure , Line 1.
At C:\Scripts\envrefresh script\newtest.ps1:26 char:19
... nvResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $ ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand'

 param(
     [string]$Environment
  )


 # Step 2: Define SQL connection details

$serverInstance = "removed"
$database = "removed"


# Set up logging

$logFilePath = "C:\Logs\ScriptLog.txt"
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

function LogMessage {
param (
    [string]$message
)

$logMessage = "$timestamp - $message"
Add-content -Path $logFilePath -Value $logMessage
}

LogMessage "Script execution started."

try {
# Step 3: Look up sproc upSelectEnvRefreshEnvironment passing the parameter from step 1
$envResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database -Query "EXEC     
upSelectEnvRefreshEnvironment @Environment" -Variable @{"Environment" = $Environment}

# Step 4-5: Process each result

foreach ($row in $envResults) {
    $environmentID = $row.EnvironmentID
    $connectionName = $row.ConnectionName

    # Step 6: Connect to the relevant database for each EnvironmentID
    $innerConnectionString = "Server=$serverInstance;Database=$connectionName;Integrated   
Security=True;"
    
    # Pass the value of LiveDBUser = NonLiveDBUser to sproc upEnvRefreshRenameDBUsers
    $permissionsResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database - 
Query "EXEC upSelectEnvRefreshPermissionsMapping @EnvironmentID" -Variable @{"EnvironmentID" = 
$environmentID}
    
    foreach ($permRow in $permissionsResults) {
        $liveDBUser = $permRow.LiveDBUser
        $nonLiveDBUser = $permRow.NonLiveDBUser

        # Step 7: Execute the sproc upEnvRefreshRenameDBUsers
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database "DevOps" -Query "EXEC 
dbo.upEnvRefreshRenameDBUsers @LiveDBUser, @NonLiveDBUser" -Variable @{"LiveDBUser" = 
$liveDBUser; "NonLiveDBUser" = $nonLiveDBUser}

        LogMessage "Renamed DB users: LiveDBUser=$liveDBUser, NonLiveDBUser=$nonLiveDBUser"
    }
}

LogMessage "Script execution completed successfully."
}
catch {
LogMessage "Error occurred: $_"
}


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-3-invoke-a-script-and-pass-in-variable-values-from-a-string It's using sqlcmd scripting variables, not normal SQL parameters. Maybe use DbaTolls instead: Invoke-DbaQuery https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html which can do proper parameterization.

Step 3 is giving an error : The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@environment' can be used only as
an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$environment'.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
